# Playwright get objectId from ElementHandle like Puppeteer element.remoteObject().objectId

Tags: puppeteer, playwright

Is it possible to get `objectId` from `ElementHandlelike` in Playwright like in Puppeteer `element.remoteObject().objectId`?
Thanks!

In puppeteer:

```
let elementHandle = await page.evaluateHandle(() => document.querySelector('a'));  
let objectId = elementHandle.remoteObject().objectId;
```

Playwright??

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this , may be somebody can suggest you better alternate way to achieve the same goal.

Comment: I find the element I need through the Chrome DevTools Protocol. I use the DOM.getNodeForLocation call. I need to select it in Playwright. 

I can find the xpath to the element in the dev protocol, and then xpath in Playwright. This is a slow solution.

Answer (score 0):

As of the time of writing, I do not see the same remoteObject method in Playwright’s docs for its comparable handles. May be something to submit an issue in their GitHub for if you have a need for it?

Comment: this is more suited as comment than as an answer.

Comment: I felt like in this case the answer to the question posed was “no”. That being said, I was torn about where to put it, and like your comment asking for clarification about his goal in case there’s another approach entirely to suggest.